# Using an AppleScript to kill an AppleScript

Tags: terminal, applescript

I have an AppleScript I use to set up my AppleTV screen sharing, sometimes it gets stuck and I have to kill it to try again. So I'd like to write a script that kills any running scripts and then run the script again.

Problem is I can't work out a way to do it that doesn't kill the parent script itself.

I can see using

```
ps axc
```

that the file has the path

> /Applications/Connect Screen Mirroring - Master
> Bedroom.app/Contents/MacOS/applet

So I tried using

```
set PID to do shell script "(ps ax | grep \"Connect Screen Mirroring - Master Bedroom\" | grep applet | awk '{print $1}')"

do shell script "kill " & PID
```

But that gives me the error

> sh: line 0: kill: 88944 89410 89411: arguments must be process or job
> IDs

I think the problem is that the first script is giving me back a 2nd, and sometimes a 3rd, unexpected PID, so if I could just find a way to filter that out I might be good.

If I run just

```
set PID to do shell script "ps ax | grep \"Connect Screen Mirroring - Master Bedroom\" | grep applet"
```

I get back

> "89474   ??  S      0:00.33 /Applications/Connect Screen Mirroring -
> Master Bedroom.app/Contents/MacOS/applet 89485   ??  S      0:00.00 sh
> -c ps ax | grep "Connect Screen Mirroring - Master Bedroom" | grep applet"

Best as I can tell, that second thing getting returned is the shell command itself.

Any suggestions on how to ignore that one? Or a better way to do this altogether?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I'd do it:

In **Terminal**:

```vash
kill $(ps ax | awk '/[C]onnect Screen Mirroring - Master Bedroom/{print $1}')
```

Using the `do shell script` *command* in **AppleScript**:

```applescript
do shell script "kill $(ps ax | awk '/[C]onnect Screen Mirroring - Master Bedroom/{print $1}'); exit 0"
```

Using `awk` eliminates the need to *pipe* to `grep` twice while allowing it to return only the *value* of the first column of `ps` output, which is the `PID`, and by placing square braces around the first character `[C]` it isolates the output to the occurrence being looked for, not what's generated by the `awk` *command* itself.

Using **command substitution**, `$(...)`, it returns only the `PID` to the `kill` *command*.

Comment: Awesome, that works great! I just needed to put it in an if statement for when it's not there to kill and I'm golden.

`set PID to (do shell script "echo $(ps ax | awk '/[C]onnect Screen Mirroring - Master Bedroom/{print $1}')")
if (PID is not equal to "") then
 do shell script "kill $(ps ax | awk '/[C]onnect Screen Mirroring - Master Bedroom/{print $1}')"
end if`

Comment: @DrunkTankGunner, You do not need to use an `if` _statement_, simply add `;exit 0` directly after the **command substitution**, `$(...);exit 0`, which I forgot to add, sorry. See updated answer.